# Microsoft Graph API getting error querying for guest accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test a few queries. One is to get a list of the Guest user accounts in Azure AD (Azure B2B/B2C).

I use one of the sample queries:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType%20eq%20'guest'](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType%20eq%20%27guest%27)

against a customer's Azure AD and I get back the json results of all the guest users.

But when I run this against my Azure AD tenant, I get this:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property
> named 'userType' on type
> 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Web.Models._1._0.Profile'.

My Azure AD tenant is license type of "Azure AD Free" - not sure if that is the cause or it matters. I am the global admin of my Azure AD tenant.

Is this due to some other setting in my Azure AD tenant? Or is it because it's Azure AD Free license? I am able to create guest accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The requested URL is correct. You should sign in with a **Member account** when using Microsoft Graph Explorer. If you log in to a guest account, it will return this error.

[image]

**Or** you could use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) based on application in Postman. Make sure you have added the appropriate permissions.

Get access token:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={client_id}
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret={client_secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Call MS Graph API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType%20eq%20'guest'
Authorization: Bear <access_token>
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: I added a new member account and it worked. But the account I was using was also a member account - the account I use to log into the Azure portal, and is a Global Administrator.  I noticed above that when I gave that user permissions using Modify Permissions in the Graph app, I would click Consent on Directory.ReadWrite.All, but I would not get the Consent window. Doesn't make sense to me, but I'll use the other member account I set up. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @mannaggia. I tried to reproduce it. When the `Creation type` of the account is invitation even though the user type has changed to member, it will also return this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzDs8.png